# Not possible to hide a QMenu object QMenu::setVisible()?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.3, qmenu, qaction

I have built up a `QMenu MainMenu` on top of my `MainWindow` in my application. As everybody is used to it, I have following `QMenu` Main menus:

> File - Edit - SuperHeavyExpertMenus - Settings - Help

I would like to hide the sub tree `SuperHeaverExpertMenus` initially, on program start, because it conatins a lot of settings, which might confuse beginner users.

I want to show that sub tree with `SuperHeavyExpertMenu`, when a checkbox in Settings is true, for instance.

I can hide the children `QActions` of the `QMenu` s above, vie `QAction:setVisible(false)` . but I can do that for the `QMenu` ?

Is there a way to hide the `QMenu` ?

Comment: Hide [Menu action](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qmenu.html#menuAction).

Comment: @Amartel I can not see a possiblity to hi hide a QMenu with that? I am not interesetes in the QActions. I am already able to hide the QActions. But the QMenu are still visible in the main menu. I want to hide a QMenu.

Comment: @RalfWickum In this case the word "action" just means "thing that can go in a menu".  From the QMenu description: *"There are four kinds of action items: separators, actions that show a submenu, widgets, and actions that perform an action."*  SuperHeavyExpertMenus would be an "action", of the second kind.

Comment: Not "menu's actions". **Menu action**. I posted a link to a documentation. Follow it.

Comment: Yes, actually, myMenu->menuAction()->setvisible(false) solved my problem.

Answer (score 28):

If I understood correctly your problem, the way you can solve it is whit something like this:

```
ui->menuYouWantToHide->menuAction()->setVisible(false);
```

I hope to be useful.

Comment: `menuAction.setVisible(False)` works in python pyqt5.

Answer (score 3):

Qmenu doesn't have `setVisible()`, or `hide()`, but you can change the title instead:

```
ui->MenuYouWantToHide->setTitle("");
```

This will remove the title, and therefore the "Action" that make up the button in your GUI.

Comment: Indeed when you do: **menu->setTitle("")** it's like **menu->hide()**. Then when you set a title later the menu is displayed with all actions within.

Comment: @Patapoom only difference that it is still "visible", which may affect some logic relying on it. Note, that it wouldn't disable shortcut key associated with same action.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility and enable-ity of QAction-based widgets can be controlled via `QAction` object connected with them.

Qt documentation, even latest versions omit multiple accessor functions from list of public ones. Instead they are referenced under relevant getters, e.g. `QAction::setVisible` is listed under `QAction::isVisible` topic.